# System dependent limitations for code

Tags: c, system-dependent

With the function:

```
int five(int n)
{
    if ((n%5)==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Why are the limitations of this positive numbers only even if there is no remainder?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. It works for all `int` values. (Better would be `return n % 5 == 0;`, though)

Answer (score 2):

for n == -2, some hardware will compute `n%5` as 3, while other hardware evaluates it as 2.  To accommodate that , the standard leaves `%` ambiguous for negative values.

Comment: “the standard leaves % ambiguous for negative values.” Not since C99. Division rounds towards zero and modulo is defined such that `(a/b)*b + a%b` equals `a`. (6.5.5:6)

Comment: by mathematical definition -2%5 == 3 == (-2+5)%5, http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52343.html

Comment: @0x90 `%` operator in C is a remainder and not a modulo operator.